# What is the definition of "ConceptWeight" in WordData?

Tags: curated-data

The documentation states that the "ConceptWeight" property is a rough estimate of semantic importance, I'd like to know how this is computed exactly, is there any way to find out?

Comment: Just in case http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/WordDataSourceInformation.html

Comment: I believe the ConceptWeight is a rough measure of how frequently a particular word is used with a specified grammatical or lexical function.  For instance, WordData["the", "ConceptWeight"] gives {the, Determiner} -> 1., meaning "the" is always used as a determiner.  Sometimes the ConceptWeight > 1, so there must be a non-obvious normalization at hand.  Try with "too" to see another example.

Comment: I'd like to have this answered, I want to know if `ConceptWeight` is comparable between words, as well as between meanings of the same word.